# Testing urls django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a flatpage in my website. I created it by writing this:

urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),path('facts/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),]

After that in admin page I created a page about-me, so the whole url for that page is ‘localhost/facts/about-me/’
I tried to write test for this page:

```
class StaticURLTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.guest_client = Client()

   def test_about_author(self):
       response = self.guest_client.get('/facts/about-me/')
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But I get the following error:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias ‘default’…
```

Can’t figure out why. Maybe smb was facing the same problem.

I thought that the error was because of the flatpage but, the same error occured when I tried to test url of the Task model

```
urlpatterns = [path('task/<slug:slug>/',views.task, name='task'),]
```

Test:

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()

        Task = Task.objects.create(
            title='Title',
            slug=' test-slug',
            description='Desc',
        )


    def setUp(self):
        self.guest_client = Client()
        user = get_user_model()
        self.user = user.objects.create_user(username='Bob')

    def test_task_url_exists_at_desired_location_authorized(self):
        response = self.guest_client.get('/task/test-slug/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I tried to change    `response = self.guest_client.get('/task/test-slug/')`    to    `response = self.guest_client.get(reverse('/task/'))`    but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do these URLs work when you access them via the dev server?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes,the do

Comment: Did you try ``force_login(user)``?